# A counterexample for an equation between arbitrary relations

Tags: category-theory, relations, relation-algebra

It seems that the following equation does not hold always for the arbitrary relations R1,R1 and R3:

> $R1.(R2\cap R3)=(R1.R2)\cap(R1.R3)$

Instead, the right axiom is the following:

> $R1.(R2\cap R3) \subseteq (R1.R2)\cap(R1.R3)$

I wrote *dot* for relation composition, and $\cap$ sign for relation intersection.

**Can anybody please think of any counterexample for the first equation?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for a simplest example
$$R_1=\{(a,x),(a,y)\},\\
R_2=\{(x,z)\},\quad R_3=\{(y,z)\}\,.$$
Note also that we have equality with *union* instead of intersection.

Comment: Does this happen when $R2\cap R3=\emptyset$? or it is possible to have other situations too?! In other words, if I add $R2\cap R3\neq\emptyset$ to the first axiom then it holds true?

Comment: No. Take any counterexample where $R_2\cap R_3=\emptyset$, then add, say $(s,s)$ to each of $R_1,R_2,R_3$ for an element $s$ that was not present in them.